# How to calculate lead time from a list of confirmations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with confirmations for parts processed through operations within a factory.

```
| PartNumber | Plant | OperationNumber | ConfirmationDate | ConfirmationTime |
| PartA      | Pl_A  | 300             | 2021-01-28       | 13:33:20         |
| PartB      | Pl_A  | 300             | 2021-01-28       | 13:33:20         |
| PartA      | Pl_A  | 500             | 2021-01-29       | 14:33:20         |
| PartB      | Pl_A  | 500             | 2021-01-29       | 14:33:20         |
| PartA      | Pl_A  | 800             | 2021-01-30       | 15:33:20         |
| PartB      | Pl_A  | 800             | 2021-01-30       | 15:33:20         |
```

What I am trying to return is the unique identifiers for that entry(PartNumber, Plant, OperationNumber) and the difference between the confirmation datetime and the last entry's confirmation datetime(highest operation number that is less than that one).

Desired Output:

```
| PartNumber | Plant | OperationNumber | LeadTime            | ConfirmationDateTime |
| PartA      | Pl_A  | 300             | NULL                | 2021-01-28 13:33:20  |
| PartA      | Pl_A  | 500             | 0000-00-01 01:00:00 | 2021-01-29 14:33:20  |
| PartA      | Pl_A  | 800             | 0000-00-01 01:00:00 | 2021-01-30 15:33:20  |
| PartB      | Pl_A  | 300             | NULL                | 2021-01-28 13:33:20  |
| PartB      | Pl_A  | 500             | 0000-00-01 01:00:00 | 2021-01-29 14:33:20  |
| PartB      | Pl_A  | 800             | 0000-00-01 01:00:00 | 2021-01-30 15:33:20  |
```

Comment: Why is the 300 operations excluded from your output? What is the logic to exclude that?

Comment: In my example, operation 300 is the first operation. In order to find that leadtime, I would need to find its original posting date within another table, which i am hoping will be a simple case statement if the calculation to find it in a previous entry returns nothing.

Comment: Use analytic function `lead()` or `lag()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a timespan data type - so processing the query to get your output format of `0000-00-01 01:00:00` would need to use a function - there are examples easily found so will leave that part to you.

Use the LAG function to get the baseline information though

```
SELECT PartNumber,
   Plant,
   OperationNumber,
   CAST(ConfirmationDate as datetime) + CAST(ConfirmationTime as datetime),
   DATEDIFF(second, LAG(CAST(ConfirmationDate as datetime) + CAST(ConfirmationTime as datetime)) OVER (PARTITION BY PartNumber ORDER BY OperationNumber), (CAST(ConfirmationDate as datetime) + CAST(ConfirmationTime as datetime)))
FROM <your table>
```

Comment: That looks close, but for the LAG part, how am I telling it to find the last row where PartNumber AND Plant matches? I am getting some negative values making me think it is finding the same part number in another plant that was confirmed after this one at a previous operation.